# Different configurations for JUnit 5 and JUnit 4 in gradle

Tags: gradle, mockito, junit4, junit5

I need to run JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests in my application. How should I configure gradle file to run these two separate tests with some common sets of dependencies and some dependencies specific to them. E.g. JUnit 5 run should only use Jupiter dependencies and Junit 4 should use powermock dependency. However, some common dependencies are used by both.

Comment: Different dependencies require different (sub)projects in Gradle. But maybe you can clarify why separating dependencies is important for you.

JUnit 5 Platform is explicitly designed to allow more than one test engine (eg Jupiter and Vintage) in the same project. Why not go with it?

Comment: The problem is with PowerMockito. It doesn't work with JUnit 5 and some of our legacy test cases are written with PowerMockito. So, I need to run them with Junit 4 coupled with PowerMockito.

Comment: Using different subproject should be the cleanest solution. However since JUnit4 and JUnit5 use different annotatins and engines, there is not really a possibility that one engine runs test for the other.